# C# purely functional dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, collections, functional-programming

Does there exist (if not in the standard library, then perhaps as a Nuget package) a class, suitable for use from C#, that provides a purely functional dictionary? That is, where adding or removing a key, will return a new dictionary while leaving the original one unchanged?

Comment: Eh, `ImmutableDictionary<K,V>`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx When you manipulate an immutable dictionary a copy of the original dictionary is made, manipulations applied and a new immutable dictionary is returned.

Comment: You are misusing the word `functional`. You are asking about a read-only or immutable dictionary. There are classes that provide both behaviours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for *immutable* collections, `ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in your case:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx

> When you manipulate an immutable dictionary a **copy** of the original
>   dictionary is made, manipulations applied and a **new immutable
>   dictionary** is returned.

Comment: In case someone wonders about the difference between read-only collections like the [`ReadOnlyDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx) and the immutable collections like the [`ImmutableDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467063(v=vs.111).aspx): the former doesn't provide methods to modify the collection, but it's just a wrapper around the original, modifiable collection, if that is changed also the readonly collection is modified. The immutable collections aren't wrappers, they can't be changed.

Comment: ... but they provide methods to "modify" them like [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466983(v=vs.111).aspx) which work similar to  the `string` methods, they return a new modified immutable collection, but the old one remains unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

I found ImmutableDictionary from System.Collections.Immutable. You can find more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The question should be rephrased as "Does .NET have any read-only or immutable dictionaries"? The answer is yes to both.

The read-only dictionary functionality is provided by the [ReadOnlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Immutability means something else - it means that one client's view of a collection doesn't change even if another one is making changes to it. This is provided by the [ImmutableDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx) class

Answer (score 2):

The best functional dictionary (or 'map' as they're known in the functional world) is available as part of this C# functional library:

https://github.com/louthy/language-ext

Here is the map module:

https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/Map.cs

Disclaimer: I wrote it.  But the reasons for the library are to facilitate functional programming in C#.  Whereas the accepted answer of ImmutableDictionary is a more OO style interface (even if it uses immutable semantics).